# parsing json body in php from ios

Tags: php, ios, json

I am building an iOS app/web service. The iOS app sends data to a php scrip like this:

```
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSURLResponse  *res ponse = nil;

    NSArray * keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"addr", @"date", @"o_cond", nil];    
    NSArray * values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:addr, date, o_cond, nil];

    NSDictionary * info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:info options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myaddr.com/sendEmail.php"]];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

And the php received the data:

```
<?php
    // Get all the posted vars  
    $jsonInput = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $decoded = json_decode($jsonInput, true);

    $body = "Inspection Results for " . $decoded->{'addr'} . "\n\n";
    $body = $body . "Inspection date and time: " . $decoded->{'date'} . "\n\n";
    $body = $body . "Overall condition of asset: " . $decoded->{'o_cond'} . "\n\n"; ?>
```

But for some reason I am never able to receive the data on the php end. Does anyone see what is going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: What does `$jsonInput` contain?

Comment: Check $decoded to see if it contains NULL.  If so, json_decode() failed.

Comment: well the iOS app should be initiating the call, so $jsonInput should contain the data that was passed from the iOS app

Comment: Also, you should add a `Content-Type: application/json` header to the request. This is generally good practice and if iOS defaults to `multipart/form-data` (which it might) then `php://input` will not be available.

Comment: @Ranlou Yes I know what it *should* contain, but what does it *actually* contain?

Comment: I added a check for $decoded being NULL and it is... $jsonInput actually contains the json that I want to read.

Comment: $jsonInput is { "o_cond" : "not entered","addr" : "YES",  "date" : "17-12-2012 11:15" }

Comment: @Ranlou Please can you show the *exact* output of `var_dump($jsonInput);` ? The JSON looks valid, I'm wondering if it has some random non-printable char screwing it up or something.

Comment: Also use [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to find out why the decode operation failed.

Comment: Dude, you're decoding into an associative array then using that wacky `$decoded->{'addr'}` syntax, which is *not* for associative arrays.  You probably want `$decoded['addr']` instead, and to crank error reporting allll the way up, as PHP should be complaining VERY loudly.

Comment: in either case charles, the $decoded variable is NULL

Comment: @DaveRandom Obviously I am new to PHP, but I tried to do a var_dump($jsonInput) and there was nothing that came back.

Comment: @Ranlou `var_dump()` outputs data, it doesn't return anything. Add `ob_start(); var_dump($jsonInput); file_put_contents('debug.txt', ob_get_clean());` to you script and post the exact contents of the `debug.txt` file that will be created in the same directory as the script here.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$decoded['addr']` instead of `$decoded->{'addr'}`. You're telling json_decode to return an associative array (second argument is set to true) but it seems like you're trying to access an object instead.

Comment: Did you try to `print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));` yet ? It will show you what the app actually submits as raw data.